# How to remove extra space after cell swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I am using table view in a scroll.
when I scroll this `tableview` then tableView show extra space after cell in tableview .

light blue color is `tableViewCcell` and green color `tableview` background color

How to remove blank space in `tableview`?

[image]

Comment: self.tableView.footerView = UIView()

Comment: How to remove and how to use ???

Comment: Show me this error when i use your syntax:-
Cannot assign to property: 'footerView' is a method

Comment: I have very seldomly seen the need to put a tableview inside a scrollview, as the tableview itself internally contains a scrollview.  Maybe you are approaching your solution the wrong way?

Comment: @ShamDhiman what do you mean by 'black space'?

Comment: @Carpsen90 sorry sir blank space

Comment: self.tableView.tableFooterView = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the frame of the tableView footer:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let t = UITableView()

t.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```